# JavaScript/Jquery Limit the size of content and split it

Tags: javascript, regex

so I'm limiting the size of this string based on a fixed sized div, the extra characters are placed into a new div, example:  there's a limit of 5 chars and a string abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. The result should be: div abcde /div div fghij /div... It works fine with a regular string, but the problem is that my string contains htmls tags, as i'm taking input from a wysiwyg editor, and becomes unpredictable. Here's my code:

```
var content = '<?php echo $content; ?>';
var limit = 800;

var regex = new RegExp('.{1,'+limit+'}','g')

$(content.match(regex)).each(function(key,val){
    $('#mybook').append('<div>'+val+'</div>')


})
```

Thanks

Comment: *"but the problem is that my string contains htmls tags"* ... uhm... I think you'll need a much more sophisticated solution than just splitting the string into pieces.

Comment: Parse the string into HTML elements, recursively iterate over all text nodes, keep track of the length of the processed text nodes. Then split the next node at the right position. But you have to keep track of the hierarchy of elements as well... it's not *that* trivial, but certainly doable.

Comment: Sounds hard, but I'll try, thanks tho.

Comment: rather than inserting divs, wouldn't line breaks (br) be enough for your purpose?

Comment: not really, bc the parsed string goes to a fixed sized div and the way it's structured doesn't allow it, but thanks

Comment: then I don't see how you could do it with html, you can't have the opening tag in one div and the closing tag in another div.